# Show that no $T\in M_{5\times 5}(\mathbb{Q})$ has order $8$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Before I get too far, I'll say that I think the above statement is incorrect.

Assume that $T\in M_{5\times 5}(\mathbb{Q})$, with $|T|=8$, and let $f(x)=x^8-1$. Since $f(T) = 0$, it follows that, if $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, then we must have $m(x)$ dividing $f(x)=x^8-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$.

Since $T\in M_{5\times 5}(\mathbb{Q})$, we must also have $\deg(m)\leq 5$, and so $m(x)=(x-1)^{e_1}(x+1)^{e_2}(x^2+1)^{e_3}(x^4+1)^{e_4}$, with each $e_i \in \{0,1\}$. If $e_4 = 0$, then $|T|\leq 4$; so $x^4 + 1$ must divide $m(x)$. As the largest of $T$'s invariant factors, $m(x)$ must be divisible by any smaller invariant factors; however, $x^4+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. And so, recalling our constraint on the degree of $m$, we must have $m(x) = (x-1)^{e_1}(x+1)^{e_2}(x^4+1)$, where $e_1+e_2 =1$. (By the way, $m(x)=p(x)$, the characteristic polynomial of $T$.)

At this point, my first time through the problem, I still thought I was proving the statement and wanted to show a contradiction. I wasn't sure what to do, so, using each of the possible minimal polynomials, I put $T$ in rational canonical form and plugged it into my TI-82, raising it to the eighth power, and sure enough got the identity matrix. Moreover, $T^4 \neq I$.

I've spent the summer feeling like a big stupid in algebra, so although my reasoning seems pretty tight to me, I can't help but think I'm missing something. Am I? (The question comes from a qual-prep seminar I'm sitting in on.) If the statement *is* false, does my logic check out? And what conditions would make it a true statement? It doesn't look like it works if $T$ must have order $6$; it seems as though it *does* hold for $T\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{Q})$ (again, with $|T|=8$).

Comment: You are probably correct in this (my linear algebra is rusty) but why, in the third paragraph, would $e_4 = 0$ necessarily imply $|T| \leq 4$? I see that if $e_1 = e_2 = 1$, $e_3 = 0$ or $e_1 = e_2 = e_3 =1$ the minimal polynomial would imply $|T| = 2$ or $|T| = 4$ respectively, but not in the other cases.

Comment: @BaronMingus: If $e_4 = 0$, then we'd need $m(x)$ to divide $x^4-1$, right? Just as a test, I tried out $m(x)=(x+1)(x^2+1)$. Once I used two copies of $x+1$ as the other invariant factors; the other time, I used $x^2+1$. Both times I got $T^4 = I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're right.  In particular, the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) to the polynomial $(x-1)(x^4+1)$ is a rational square matrix of size $5$ with order $8$.

Comment: Thank you! It's always nice to know I'm not crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Take $\xi = e^{\pi i /4}$ in $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$. Then $[k:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$, so the action of $k$ on itself by multiplication gives a faithful representation $\rho:k^* \to GL_4(\mathbb{Q})\subset GL_5(\mathbb{Q})$. Since $\xi$ has order $8$, so does $\rho(\xi)$.

Comment: This one of those answers I'm gonna have to hold on to for a while and look at once I've seen some more algebra. One question that I *know* I have: $k$ looks like a degree-2 extension; did you mean to adjoin an $i$ or something as well?--to give us $\xi$? (I haven't done any representation theory yet, so I'm not sure where to start with my other questions! Maybe this: Is $\rho$ multiplication by $\xi$?)

Comment: Thanks, I did mean to adjoin $i$ as well. For $\rho$, consider $k/\mathbb{Q}$ as a $4$-dimensional vector space. The map $x \to \alpha x$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear for fixed $x$, so it defines a map $k \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Q})$ via that identification. Restricting it to $k^*$ gives a map $\rho:k^* \to GL_4(\mathbb{Q})$.